# Why doesn't EUtilsSummary extract the journal name?

Tags: r

I am trying to extract the journal names that a scientist published,
I used to do that easily but now, it gives me full of NA and not much info.

```
library(RISmed)

res <- EUtilsSummary('David M. Sabatini', type='esearch', db='pubmed')
```

Comment: @akrun
 yes do you have any suggestion?

Comment: I tried with CRAN version and the github and I couldn't get the journal link.  That is why I asked whether you had the same version or not

Comment: @akrun
 Yes the same, I am just wondering why or how to get it fixed

Comment: I am not sure.  May be you can raise an [issue](https://github.com/skoval/RISmed/issues) in their github page